# Entity Framework 6 Code First, Composite Foreign Key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'll describe a simplified version: I have tables TableA and TableB with id's, and TableC with two columns that reference id's in TableA and TableB. When I run Entity Data Model Wizard with Code First from Database and select all tables, it generates models for TableA and TableB, but not TableC. TableC is included in mapping of TableA. Why?

If I try to create a model for TableC manually (or by running the wizard and selecting only TableC) and then adding DbSet for TableC to my DbContext, I get 
a runtime error:

> TableATableB: Name: The EntitySet 'TableATableB' with schema 'dbo' and table 'TableC' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table.

Would someone be able explain how I can access TableC model? I'm sure I'm missing something but I'm not able to figure out what exactly...

Here's the simplified SQL to create these tables in database 'test':

```
CREATE TABLE [test].[dbo].TableA   
( 
    [id] nvarchar(36) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([id])
)

CREATE TABLE [test].[dbo].[TableB]  
(
    [id] nvarchar(36) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TableB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([id])
)

CREATE TABLE [test].[dbo].[TableC]
( 
    [aId] nvarchar(36) NOT NULL,
    [bId] nvarchar(36) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TableC] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([aId],[bId])
)

ALTER TABLE [test].[dbo].[TableC]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TableC_TableA]
    FOREIGN KEY([aId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TableA]([id])

ALTER TABLE [test].[dbo].[TableC]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TableC_TableB]
    FOREIGN KEY([bId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TableB]([id])
```

This is the `DbContext` that the wizard generates:

```
    public virtual DbSet<TableA> TableA { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TableB> TableB { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>()
            .HasMany(e => e.TableB)
            .WithMany(e => e.TableA)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("TableC").MapLeftKey("aId").MapRightKey("bId"));
    }
```

And this is the model for TableA (similar for TableB):

```
[Table("TableA")]
public partial class TableA
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public TableA()
    {
        TableB = new HashSet<TableB>();
    }

    [StringLength(36)]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TableB> TableB { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, if I generate a model for just TableC:

```
[Table("TableC")]
public partial class TableC
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(36)]
    public string aId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(36)]
    public string bId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can i know how you are adding this from Database?

Comment: Did you checked `Include Foreign Key columns in the model` while creating the model ?

Comment: I just do Add -> New Item -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model -> Code First from database -> select all tables in the database

Comment: Yes, `Include foreign key columns in the model` checkbox is checked and grayed out, I can't even uncheck it.

Comment: Why do you need to?  The model generated should give you everything you need to modify the data in TableC, which is just a many-to-many linking table without any attributes.

Comment: @MarcL. Suppose I create a new row a1 in TableA and a new row b1 in TableB, how can I create a row in TableC with a1 and b1? I just don't know how to access TableC...

Comment: In EF, you would simply add `a1` to the `TableB` collection on the `TableA` object, and save changes.  That would create the association, which would translate down to the database as additional `(a1,b1)` row in TableC.

Comment: @MarcL. Thanks! Now I understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the default behaviour of Entity Framework.
You simply don't need TableC in your Code. 
OR-Mappers try to hide the complexity of Databases from us developers and Entity Framework helps you because it hides this n to m relation and constructs a .Net like approach with two collections for you.
What benefit yould you have on having TableC as an Entity?

Comment: I agree, for reading I don't need TableC, I already know id's from TableA and TableB. But what about writing into TableC, how can I create a new row in TableC if I can't even see it?

Comment: Just add an Entity of TableB to the Collection TableB of the TableA Entity. And call SaveChanges() of course. Then check what happened in the Database.

Comment: would you clarify how? I can create new rows in TableA and TableB, but that doesn't affect TableC.

Comment: var tabAInstance = MyContext.TableAs.First();
// Create an Instance of TableB
var instTabB = new TableB() {...};
tabAInstance.TableB.Add(instTabB);
MyContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: That doesn't give me access to TableC. I can see MyContext.TableAs.First().TableB, but not TableC.

Comment: I told you in my answer that Entity Framework hides TableC - this is fully intended! Why would you need TableC?

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much. Initially I had more fields in TableC and not seeing the model confused me...

Comment: :-) Glad to help you.